# baffled by a mypy "arg-type" error in pyspark in a basic filter statement

Tags: pyspark, mypy

The line of PySpark code is:

```
df = df.filter(F.col("date_time") != "")
```

mypy error I'm getting is:

> Argument 1 to "filter" of "DataFrame" has incompatible type "Column";
> expected "list[Any] | None"  [arg-type]

versions:
`pyspark==3.5.0`
`mypy==1.6.1`